# Why can't I connect to this site via HTTPS?

Tags: networking, proxy, windows-10, ssl, openssl

Ever since I upgraded to Windows 10, there is a single site I visit that I simply can't connect to. Other people I've talked to don't have this issue. I can access it fine from my phone while on the same network. I've reached out to the company that owns the site and they can't replicate it either.

In my own poking around, I got the openssl 1.0.1p 64 bit version for Windows. I don't even know if this is the one I need, and I've read about there being bugs in some but not others. There are so many! Here is the command I used:

```
openssl s_client -msg -debug -connect secure.paizo.com:443
```

And that gets me

```
CONNECTED(000001B8)

write to -0x52ea5b30 [-0x52e910e0] (297 bytes => 297 (0x129))
0000 - 16 03 01 01 24 01 00 01-20 03 03 38 d1 1f 78 ac   ....$... ..8..x.
0010 - 59 8c 67 30 45 83 f5 18-7a f0 ec 74 b0 d2 56 09   Y.g0E...z..t..V.
0020 - 71 f6 0d 4c 40 02 7c a6-f2 a7 69 00 00 8a c0 30   q..L@.|...i....0
0030 - c0 2c c0 28 c0 24 c0 14-c0 0a 00 a3 00 9f 00 6b   .,.(.$.........k
0040 - 00 6a 00 39 00 38 00 88-00 87 c0 32 c0 2e c0 2a   .j.9.8.....2...*
0050 - c0 26 c0 0f c0 05 00 9d-00 3d 00 35 00 84 c0 2f   .&.......=.5.../
0060 - c0 2b c0 27 c0 23 c0 13-c0 09 00 a2 00 9e 00 67   .+.'.#.........g
0070 - 00 40 00 33 00 32 00 9a-00 99 00 45 00 44 c0 31   .@.3.2.....E.D.1
0080 - c0 2d c0 29 c0 25 c0 0e-c0 04 00 9c 00 3c 00 2f   .-.).%.......<./
0090 - 00 96 00 41 00 07 c0 11-c0 07 c0 0c c0 02 00 05   ...A............
00a0 - 00 04 c0 12 c0 08 00 16-00 13 c0 0d c0 03 00 0a   ................
00b0 - 00 15 00 12 00 09 00 ff-01 00 00 6d 00 0b 00 04   ...........m....
00c0 - 03 00 01 02 00 0a 00 34-00 32 00 0e 00 0d 00 19   .......4.2......
00d0 - 00 0b 00 0c 00 18 00 09-00 0a 00 16 00 17 00 08   ................
00e0 - 00 06 00 07 00 14 00 15-00 04 00 05 00 12 00 13   ................
00f0 - 00 01 00 02 00 03 00 0f-00 10 00 11 00 23 00 00   .............#..
0100 - 00 0d 00 20 00 1e 06 01-06 02 06 03 05 01 05 02   ... ............
0110 - 05 03 04 01 04 02 04 03-03 01 03 02 03 03 02 01   ................
0120 - 02 02 02 03 00 0f 00 01-01                        .........
>>> TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 0124], ClientHello
    01 00 01 20 03 03 38 d1 1f 78 ac 59 8c 67 30 45
    83 f5 18 7a f0 ec 74 b0 d2 56 09 71 f6 0d 4c 40
    02 7c a6 f2 a7 69 00 00 8a c0 30 c0 2c c0 28 c0
    24 c0 14 c0 0a 00 a3 00 9f 00 6b 00 6a 00 39 00
    38 00 88 00 87 c0 32 c0 2e c0 2a c0 26 c0 0f c0
    05 00 9d 00 3d 00 35 00 84 c0 2f c0 2b c0 27 c0
    23 c0 13 c0 09 00 a2 00 9e 00 67 00 40 00 33 00
    32 00 9a 00 99 00 45 00 44 c0 31 c0 2d c0 29 c0
    25 c0 0e c0 04 00 9c 00 3c 00 2f 00 96 00 41 00
    07 c0 11 c0 07 c0 0c c0 02 00 05 00 04 c0 12 c0
    08 00 16 00 13 c0 0d c0 03 00 0a 00 15 00 12 00
    09 00 ff 01 00 00 6d 00 0b 00 04 03 00 01 02 00
    0a 00 34 00 32 00 0e 00 0d 00 19 00 0b 00 0c 00
    18 00 09 00 0a 00 16 00 17 00 08 00 06 00 07 00
    14 00 15 00 04 00 05 00 12 00 13 00 01 00 02 00
    03 00 0f 00 10 00 11 00 23 00 00 00 0d 00 20 00
    1e 06 01 06 02 06 03 05 01 05 02 05 03 04 01 04
    02 04 03 03 01 03 02 03 03 02 01 02 02 02 03 00
    0f 00 01 01
read from -0x52ea5b30 [-0x52e8bb80] (7 bytes => 0 (0x0))
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 297 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
---
```

Also from my own poking around, I understand that apparently I'm not getting anything back from my client's hello message. In the company's response, they were curious if I wasn't using some proxy that was messing things up. I don't use a proxy. It's not configured under Windows. There aren't any on my router.

Can anyone shed some light and maybe explain the above output? I'm a pretty technical person but this area is a mystery to me, and this is a site I'm used to visiting often.

A quick clarification: I **can** connect to the unsecured portion of the site, paizo.com. The SSL portion is the only part that I'm having trouble with.

Comment: You have tried other browsers?

Comment: Yes. Chrome seems to force the connection to happen over the SSL version, if available. Firefox seems to be content with which ever I entered, HTTP or HTTPS, but some portions of the site are forced through an SSL connection such as posting on their message board so that doesn't work for me. Edge seems to always redirect me to the HTTP version even if I entered an HTTPS address.

Comment: Are you using a proxy? Or is there some firewall in your network? And no, OpenSSL is not needed for having SSL support in Windows, because Microsoft has its own SSL stack and Chrome and Firefox contain their own SSL stack too. And are you sure that the secure.paizo.com resolves to the correct IP address for you - 207.115.69.198 for me (CNAME to paizo.com)

Comment: No, I know it's not needed for SSL in Windows. I downloaded it as a tool to help diagnose the problem. I have a firewall on my router and on my PC. Since I can connect on my phone, it wouldn't be the router. I don't have rules like that. I disabled A/V and all that as well on my desktop, but it had no effect. But, no, no proxy as I said. None that I've configured or seen in Windows, my browsers, or my router. I also get that same IP doing an nslookup on my desktop.

Comment: For what it's worth, that site does have an erroneous 301 redirect when using that domain with HTTP, instead of HTTPS: http://secure.paizo.com redirects to `http://paizo.comhttps//secure.paizo.com/`. That by itself is unrelated to your problem, but it would make me assume that server is not configured very well.

Comment: @Arjan Could it cause a problem if something else related had a problem?

Comment: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=secure.paizo.com shows ssl connections should be successful from Windows 10 + Edge. Are you sure you aren't being sent through a transparent proxy that is altering your traffic? Also, you say you tried Chrome, Firefox, and IE, please confirm it did not work in any of the browsers.

Comment: The SSL handshake might fail because the website is using as older SSL version. Try to verify this by adding to the openssl command one of the parameters `-ssl3` or `-tls1`. Or use nmap to scan the server for supported version ; `nmap --script ssl-cert,ssl-enum-ciphers secure.paizo.com` and add new info to your post.

Comment: @ssnobody I tried Chrome, Firefox, and Edge. I've removed IE from Win 10 via the Features window. As to there being a transparent proxy, that's kind of a wildcard. I'm not seeing any kind of proxy on my machine or router, but if it's there I don't know how to detect it. I can do tracerts all day but eventually I'm out of my ISP's machines and can't really verify things from there. Would this be something my ISP could help detect if I called their support line?

Comment: @harrymc I did some experimentation with that, specifically SSL3, TLS1/11/12, but didn't get a successful connection with any of them and is why I didn't have it in my post. The output varied slightly but that was it. I'll try the nmap and see what it says.

Comment: Check if you are getting success with this - `openssl s_client -connect google.com:443`. If not then it means something is wrong with your `openssl` installation. As per my guess, google will also not work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow my local configuration got messed up. I was accepting TLS 1.2 connections but my computer was actually connecting over 1.0. I wiped my computer and it works as expected. This goes to show to me, once again, to not upgrade Windows and to only do clean installs.

I have a metric crap ton of configuration and installation work to do now. Oi...

Thank you, everyone, for all your help.

Comment: How did you know you where connecting  over TLS 1.0 ? probably reading a Wireshark capture?

Comment: Nope. I went to https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewMyClient.html and https://www.howsmyssl.com/. For whatever reason, I was supporting the latest TLS version but not actually connecting over it. I went back to the other sites I visit and looked more closely and saw I was connected over TLS 1.0. That became a fundamental issue with my machine to me rather than one errant site so I wiped it and reinstalled Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Install Wireshark in your PC and perform a traffic capture during a a failed connection attempt. Save the capture as a pcap file. Analyzing the traffic exchange you'll be able to focus in the problem.

Comment: I've poked around Wireshark but didn't feel I had a good grasp on what was going on. I'll do this and see what I find.

Comment: you can also capture a good connection and compare both..., if you get lost just upload the captures somewhere.

Comment: From what I see there's a Reset in there that Wireshark highlights. I'm unsure of the meaning of it though like for what to look for in other packets and whatnot. [Here's the pcap](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xnicf7fffdkc1z0/Paizo%20Failed%20SSL.pcap?dl=0).

Comment: the client sends the "Client Hello" then the host for some reason sends an [ACK, FIN] (Acknowledgement + desire to close the connection) but the client does not answers back with [ACK, FIN] then waits and finally aborts when the the host had already close the link. You should've added a non-failing capture for comparison.

Comment: For a non-failing capture, would that be of the same site but HTTP, another site but HTTPS, or something else?

Comment: first 1) same site with HTTPS using the same browser from a different PC then 2) different site with HTTPS using the same browser in the same PC

Comment: I'll try to do this tonight. Unfortunately, this PC is the only Win 10 machine I have. Otherwise, it's Android devices.